# Ubuntu 12.04LTS becoms slow and jerky randomly for a mintue and then becomes normal by itself

Tags: performance, syslog

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my Toshiba satellite L510 and I have only Ubuntu installed. The system becomes slow and jerky by itself after every 10minutes or so and the remains like that for less than one minute

Comment: I added the tag `performance`. I'm not sure why you tagged the question with `syslog`? Does the log files say anything special after such a lag? Have a look at `/var/log/{dmesg,kern.log,syslog,messages}` etc. Also, it may help to open "system monitor" to see what caused the lag.

Comment: check that also but everything normal there

Comment: Sounds like a cronjob if it is recurrent. What does `sudo crontab -l` say?

Comment: it says

Http://freetexthost.com/jrbzz5bvdm

open the URL to see

Comment: That only lists root's cron though, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/137173/168034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had issues with (temporary) hanging/freezes/sluggishness on a (somewhat older) laptop that was (somewhat) resolved by using GNOME Classic (aka GNOME Fallback, & still is gnome3, btw); but my eventual solution was to use gnome2/mate (eventually replacing Ubuntu altogether with the Linux "mint" distro). Perhaps too much cruft from too many upgrades, or maybe the old laptop just couldn't handle the demands of unity/gnome3; I'm sure the situation will improve, but until then, cheers, "mate".